# How to resize, organize, and align images on a wafer map using Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, dictionary, resize, alignment

I'm trying to scale, rotate, and align images into a wafer map using Matlab. I'm able to resize and rotate the images, but I haven't been able to find a way to align them on a grid.

I have an image that is unique to every space on the image linked below. I would like to align a series of images to it's corresponding space on the map. (0101 = location 1,1 on the wafer, and so on). The images are currently .jpg files which I plan on reading in as needed.

I have a table showing which file corresponds to which location, and I am able to change the file names, if needed. I would like to align an image to every space on the following map:

[Example Wafer Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK875.png)

Comment: could you post what have you tried and what exactly are you trying to achieve? for example: what are these images, how do you have them on your workspace, and what's exactly this wafer map (another image? a simple matrix?)

Comment: I've added some more details to the original question, let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: My idea was to align images onto a grid and use the same point on all of the images to align with. For example. use the top-left corner of the image as 0,0 and align that to 5,1's corner.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. If each grid box in the wafer map is say MxN. Then create an empty 10*M x 10*n image and use indexing to 'place' your images into it (?)

Comment: How would that indexing and placing be done?